# PHP check a string for something and if there save to variable

Tags: php

I am getting my URL from my site and trying to save a certain field to a variable

```
$link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";  
// example of $link = "/index.php?option=com_course&id=1&Itemid=104"
if(strpos($actual_link,'id=') !== false){
    $id =    // the number after id= in the string
}
```

basically im checking if id= exists within the string and if it does to save the number of the id to $id.

so the outcome of the example of $link listed above would be for $id = 1

Comment: Why did you wrap a single variable in quotes? Anyways, WHAT DID YOU TRY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL from the site is passing variables you can just use GET?

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you accept answer by clicking the tick :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want the first line to be `$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`.

But for requesting data like that, from an request to your own server, there's a reserved global variable: $_GET (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

It'd work like this: `$id = $_GET['id'];`